# Error using \numproduct with pgf for loop variable

Tags: siunitx, pgffor

For some reason, I am unable to use `\numproduct` command from `siunitx` with a `pgffor` loop variable.

The following code gives the expected output:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \numproduct{1x2}, \numproduct{3x5}
\end{document}
```

But when put in loop:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \foreach \i in {1x2, 3x5} {\numproduct{\i},}
\end{document}
```

it exits with error

```
Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '1x2'. \foreach \i in {1x2, 3x5} {\numproduct{\i},}
Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '3x5'. \foreach \i in {1x2, 3x5} {\numproduct{\i},}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\numproduct` command doesn't expand the input at the point it searches for `x` tokens. As such, what happens here is `\numproduct{\i}` passes `\i` to the underlying(*) `\num`, and that doesn't like a `x` token when it *does* expand the input. So you need to ensure that `\i` is expanded up-front

```latex
\foreach \i in {1x2, 3x5} {\expanded{\numproduct{\i},}}
```

### will do it for example.

- It's not quite implemented like this but conceptually this is easier to follow

Comment: There's currently an open issue about the handling of `x` here to make it more flexible: A change could mean revisit whether to expand the input to `\numproduct`.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. No wonder I was facing this issue only with `\numproduct` and not `\num`.